# In Observer sales_order_save_after Order Enitiy are not save any data of current order In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer

In Observer sales_order_save_after Order Entity are not save any data of current order In **Magento 2.3.5** I created the following function in helper and used an observer but not a success so save some default value. Is there any rule or validation that orders generated by checkout data will not save?

*Thanks in Advance.*

```
/**
 * @param $order
 * @return OrderInterface
 */
public function setCustomerAddress($order)
{
    try {
      //  $order = $this->orderInterface->load($order);


        $orderAddressInterface   = $this->orderAddressInterface->get($order->getBillingAddressId());
        $orderAddressInterface->setStreet("default");
        $orderAddressInterface->setPostcode("00000");
        $orderAddressInterface->setCity("default");
        $orderAddressInterface->save($orderAddressInterface);

        $orderAddressInterfaceBilling = $this->orderAddressInterfaceBilling;
        $orderAddressInterfaceBilling   = $orderAddressInterfaceBilling->get($order->getShippingAddressId());
        //  print_r($orderAddressInterfaceBilling->getData());
        $orderAddressInterfaceBilling->setStreet("default");
        $orderAddressInterfaceBilling->setPostcode("00000");
        $orderAddressInterfaceBilling->setCity("default");
        $orderAddressInterfaceBilling->save($orderAddressInterfaceBilling);
        $order->save();
        $this->orderRepository->save($order);
        var_dump($orderAddressInterfaceBilling->getData());
      //  exit();

        return $order;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        exit();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: First have you debug that your observer is call successfully?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya ! yes it working fine cause it create a new user as well